# what is for SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version?

Tags: php, mysql

the code is totally true but during execute i face error

## whats wrong with this code ... of course im beginner coder guys but help me please

## THE ERROR IS :

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '52, v@test.com)VALUES ('niki','52','v@test.com')' at line 1

## THE CODE IS :

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $Name= $_POST ['Name'];
   $Password = $_POST [ 'Password'];
  $Email= $_POST [ 'Email'];
   $connection = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','loginapp');
   if($connection){
      echo "Hi Dude , we are conneted";
   }else{
      die('DataBase is Failed');
   }
   $query = "INSERT INTO `users`($Name , $Password, $Email)" ; 
   $query .= "VALUES ('$Name','$Password','$Email')";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection , $query);
  if (!$result){
     die('Query FAILED'. mysqli_error($connection));
  }
}else { 
   echo "Record Create"; 
}
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: remove single quotes from values

Comment: `INSERT INTO `users`($Name , $Password, $Email)"` should probably be `INSERT INTO `users`(Name , Password, Email)"`

Comment: **Danger**: "Not hashing at all" is [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php); you need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: You should probably **look** at the value of `$query` and compare it to the SQL you are trying to generate.

Comment: thank you guys ... you are saver life

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use column names in place of variables in the insert statement.
Insted of
`$query = "INSERT INTO`users`($Name , $Password, $Email)" ; 
 $query .= "VALUES ('$Name','$Password','$Email')";`

Use something like this

`$query = "INSERT INTO`users`(Name , Password, Email)" ; 
 $query .= "VALUES ('$Name','$Password','$Email')";`